# DatePart function not working in a particular table

Tags: na

Query not working in specific table

I need to take the last quarter data.

Below query gives me the last quarter but for all the years.

select ExecutionTime from table where
DATEPART(qq, ExecutionTime) = DATEPART(q, DATEADD(q, -1, getdate()))

i wanted to get only for the current year, so i'm using the below query

AND DATEPART(yyyy, ExecutionTime) = DATEPART(yyyy, DATEADD(m, -1, getdate())) order by 1

this one is working in 1 table but not in the other.

Any suggestions pls.